# Curldown only fades in - why?

Tags: ios, ipad

In my -application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions, as the final part, I have this code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut 
                 animations:^{
                     [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.viewController.source cache:YES];
                     self.viewController.source.alpha = 1.0;
                 } completion:nil];
```

What it should do is "fade in the 'source' view and curl it down to cover the background"

Instead it just fades in the 'source' view, no curl.

Clues?

Comment: Just as curiosity ..have u tried the curl effect by removing line that sets alpha? & whats this "self.viewController.source"?

Comment: No, I have not tried it without the alpha change. The alpha for the view is set to 0 in the interface builder. The view (self.ViewController.source is a UITextView. This animation works fine elsewhere.

Comment: try changing the animation-transition to something different e.g. flip/dissolve. Coz if fade effect is working fine then problem is in transition. so do some trial attempts like this.

Comment: Solved:

It appears that parts of the animation loop isn't yet running at that point. Solution was to put the animation in a method, then from the application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions do  
   
    [self performSelector:@selector(curlInSource) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

Comment: @AndersSewerinJohansen you should either remove your question then, or answer it yourself to prevent unanswered questions here on SO.

Comment: As I'm sure you know, there's a waiting period before you can answer your own questions. In this particular case I still have another 34 minutes to wait before I can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

It appears that parts of the animation loop isn't yet running at that point. Solution was to put the animation in a method, then from the application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions do